# FreeRTOS - creating a task in place of another task?

Tags: freertos

I am using `heap_1` memory allocation. There is an initialization task `Task_ini`, from which 2 tasks `Task_1` and `Task_2` are launched. Then I delete `Task_ini`. At some point in time from `Task_1` I need to create a new task `Task_3`. How can I create `Task_3` in the FreeRTOS heap in place of `Task_ini` which has already been deleted by that time, knowing only its `TaskHandle_t`?

```
int main(void){
  xTaskCreate(Task_ini, "Task_ini", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, &htask_ini);
  vTaskStartScheduler();    
  for(;;);
}
void Task_ini(void *pParams){   
  xTaskCreate(Task_function, "Task_1", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, &param1, 1, &htask1);
  xTaskCreate(Task_function, "Task_2", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, &param2, 1, &htask2);
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
void Task_function(void *pParams){
  for(;;){
    //task code
    //...
    //end task code
    if(create == true){
      create = false;
//Here I need to create a task at the address where the "Task_ini" task was.
//My code creates a task in a new heap section, and if there is no space it will cause a memory allocation error.
      xTaskCreate(Task_function, "Task_3", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, &param3, 1, &htask3);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main idea of *heap_1* is that you can't free memory. It is simply not capable of doing so. If you want to delete tasks, you need to use other *heap_n* methods. Even in that case, you should let the kernel to do its job: It's kernels job to manage memory for FreeRTOS objects, not yours.

Actually, deleting tasks isn't considered as a good practice in general. Unless you are really low on heap space, you can simply suspend the task. In this way, you can wake it up again without any cost in case its services are required again.

It's true that an init task will become useless after the system initialization. But there is a well known solution for your init task problem:  It can evolve into another task after it completes the initialization sequence. For example, *Task_ini* can create only *Task_2*, and instead of creating a *Task_1*, it can do the *Task_1*'s job itself.

**Update:**

> It's kernels job to manage memory for FreeRTOS objects, not yours.

Actually, FreeRTOS allows you to manage the memory manually, if you prefer to do so. There are static versions of object creation functions, like `xTaskCreateStatic()`. When using these static versions, you pass two statically allocated buffers to the function for the task stack and the task control block (TCB). Then you will literally be able to place one task onto another (provided that it's deleted). To be able to use these functions, `configSUPPORT_STATIC_ALLOCATION` must be defined as `1`.

But I suggest you to avoid manual memory management unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Comment: In the `Task_ini`, I just need to wait for the `create` event and run the `Task_function(&param3)`.

Comment: Yes, this should work. But it may use additional stack memory because of saving return address. If you didn't use the same function for two tasks, you could place an infinite loop after the creation of *Task_2*, instead of jumping into the task function.

Comment: I understand it. I have such an example, since my tasks are the same function, only the parameters are different.